# How to generate Git commit e-mails using built-in mechanisms?

Tags: git, email, git-commit

The `post-receive` hook is a well-known mechanism for generating notification e-mails summarising Git commits. However, as far as I know, this hook is only called when commits are `git push`-ed into a remote repository.

How do I get Git to send notification e-mails in response to commits made to a local repository, without any pushing to a remote?

I know there is a `post-commit` hook, but my impression is that it's used for something else--perhaps validation? Moreover, the stock script is bare, without any obvious linkage to an e-mail script. I doubt one can just copy the standard `post-receive` script in its place, as the arguments passed to the `post-commit` hook seem to be different than the ones passed to `post-receive`.

I'm sure one can come up with some custom script to do this, based solely on the commit ID (presumably available in the internal hook arguments). I'm interested in a simple solution that relies on more or less stock/packaged Git scripts; a small and relatively universal shim. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *no* arguments to `post-commit`, but it does not need any since the (single) commit that was made, was made wherever `HEAD` points now that the commit is done.  Read `HEAD`: if it's a symbolic ref for a branch, there was one commit made to that branch; if it's a raw SHA-1, there was one commit made with a detached `HEAD`; if it's anything else, that's weird. :-)

This is far simpler than `post-receive` which may have received a large number of commits, a number of tag objects, and/or multiple reference updates.  The post-receive hook email generator must account for a lot more possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

[Pro Git's chapter on Git Hooks](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) covers how to deal with this.

> After the entire commit process is completed, the post-commit hook runs. It doesn’t take any parameters, but you can easily get the last commit by running `git log -1 HEAD`. Generally, this script is used for notification or something similar.

Once you've gotten the information you need from `HEAD`, you're writing a script that sends email.  You may want to fork the process of sending the email else `git commit` will wait for it to send slowing the development process.  Just be sure to get all your data about `HEAD` before you fork and exit else another commit could happen and change `HEAD`.

Comment: The post-commit hook is run by the commit command itself, so as long as you're the only one doing commits, and you wait for `git commit` to finish, you'll avoid races.  The `post-receive` hook has more of a potential problem but the information it gets on stdin is at least safe (the potential problem is that the pack lockfile has been removed by then, so a second receive-pack could remove refs and then run a gc, but in practice I've never seen a problem, not that this means it's impossible...).

Comment: @torek Thanks for the info, I've removed the concurrency issue from the answer.  Still strikes me as odd they don't pass the commit ID, minimalism run rampant I guess.